# Android Build Fails with Duplicate class error for 3rd Party Libraries

Tags: android, gradle, proguard, android-build

I am importing several 3rd Party Libraries in my android project and all the AAR's of the libraries have been obfuscated by pro guard of which some of the libraries happen to have duplicate class because of the proguard configuration

Build Error

```
Duplicate class a.a.a.b.a found in modules jetified-lib1-runtime.jar (lib1.aar) and jetified-lib2-release-runtime.jar (lib2-release.aar)

Duplicate class a.a.a.b.b found in modules jetified-lib1-runtime.jar (lib1.aar) and jetified-lib2-release-runtime.jar (lib2-release.aar)
```

Any fix/workaround ?

Comment: were you able to solve this?

Comment: No. I had to ask the library team to make changes in the aar file, like keep the base package name the same and obfuscate the rest i.e classes, etc.